# Rails 5: use .where with two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm combining the two `.where` like this:

```
@questions = (FirstQuestion.where(user_id: current_user) + SecondQuestion.where(user_id: current_user)).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
```

Both `.where` searches are with one attribute... the `user_id`. But now I want to search with two attributes, the `user_id` and this `created_at >= ?", Date.today + 60.days`. So basically I want to find the object with a `user_id: current_user` and the objects that where created less then or equal to 60 days.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: There are at least a couple of ways of doing this. What has your research told you? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jvillian... I tried this after the above but with no luck `@questions.where("created_at <= ?", Date.today + 60.days)` what do you suggest?

Comment: When you try that, do you get a no method error saying that `Array` doesn't respond to `where`? If not, what do you get?

Comment: I get this error.... `undefined method where' for #<Array:0x00007f8554eabbc8> Did you mean? when`

Comment: Correct. Why do you suppose that `@questions` is an `Array` instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which would have the method `where`)? Hint: see the [docs for 'sort_by'](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by).

Comment: hmmm so something like this would work? `@questions.where.sort_by {|question| question.created_at <= Date.today + 60.days}`

Comment: You can check as many as you want using hash like for example   `FirstQuestion.where(user_id: current_user, created_at >= ?", Date.today + 60.days)`. You should refer https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where and understand how `where` works.

Comment: You should give the @AmitPatel approach a try, although I'll be a bit surprised if it works as `user_id: current_user, created_at >= ?", Date.today + 60.days` is a malformed hash. But, it's on the right path. You might consider something more like `where("id = ? AND created_at >= ?", current_user, Date.today + 60.days")`. The key is doing *all* of your database operations *before* your results get converted to an Array. BTW, you may also consider doing your `sort` (using `order`) as a database operation instead of using `sort_by`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a `SyntaxError` for this: `FirstQuestion.where(user_id: current_user, created_at >= ?", Date.today + 60.days)`

Comment: Ansd `wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: id = ? AND created_at >= ?` for this: `FirstQuestion.where("id = ? AND created_at >= ?", "current_user, Date.today + 60.days")`

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's a malformed `hash`. But, it's good to try things out to see what happens.

Comment: `FirstQuestion.where("id = ? AND created_at >= ?", current_user, Date.today + 60.days)`. "current_user, Date.today + 60.days" is a single string, not two bind variables. You have too many quotation marks in there.

Comment: I'm running out to buy some cement. Keep fiddling with it. You're getting quite close. I'll check back in after a while. Good luck!

Comment: I think the only question that is really important here.... how do you end up with a set-up in which you have a model `FirstQuestion` and `SecondQuestion`, what's so different between these questions that they should have their own Model? Especially if one of the operations later on, is joining the results... which indicates that the attributes are exactly the same. This is a code-smell IMO.

Comment: @bo-oz I agree that the whole `FirstQuestion` and `SecondQuestion` bit is code smelly. I disagree that "how do you end up with..." is the only question that is really important here. There are other important questions the OP has the opportunity to learn to ask, like, "What is the error message telling me?", "Why am I getting an `Array`?", "How do I read the docs?", "What does a well-formed hash look like?", etc. It's the whole "teach to fish" vs. "give a fish" thing. I will say, however, that your answer is on point and well-stated.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my comment as well... because it is kind of a code smell when you have models names FirstQuestion, SecondQuestion. There's really no reason for having separate models. You could probably easily model the logic via an attribute `question_depth` or something (I don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly).

With regard to your question: ActiveRecord is quite a nice class, that allows for very customizable queries. In your case, you could easily write both conditions each in a separate `where`, or create a single `where`. That's totally up to you:

```
Question.where(user: current_user).where('created_at <= ?', 60.days.from_now)
```

Or in a single where

```
Question.where('user_id = ? AND created_at <= ?', current_user.id, 60.days.from_now)
```

Also, consider using scopes on your Question model for readability and reusability:

```
class Question < AppModel
   scope :by_user, -> (user) { where(user: user) }
   scope :min_age, -> (date) { where('created_at <= ?', date) }
end
```

And use it like:

```
Question.by_user(current_user).min_age(60.days.from_now)
```

Comment: I would like to note that the [Active Record Query Interface guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html) states under [14.1 Passing in arguments](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments): "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes." It is, naturally, a matter of some personal preference.

Comment: Didn't know that... I like the arrow notation personally.. but it's a matter of taste I guess.